# Ethers.js invalid number value while deploying contract

Tags: ethers.js, uint256

I'm deploying a contract usign ethers.js 
I do it as follows:

```
const tokenWeiPrice = (answers.priceEur / ethEur) * Math.pow(10, 18);

const contract = await factory.deploy(
   answers.maxSupply,
   answers.eventName,
   answers.symbol,
   0,
   expireAfter,
   tokenWeiPrice
);
```

While deploying it throws an error

```
(node:11654) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: invalid constructor argument (arg="_ticketPrice", reason="invalid number value", value=43478260869565220, version=4.0.20)
```

the problem stays in `tokenWeiPrice` I would like to know why, in my contract this is a uint256 constructor's parameter.

Comment: You're using integer values way to large for javascript (larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`). Use `BigNumber` conclusively.

Comment: Also, `tokenWeiPrice` is likely not even an integer, so you should by the least use `Math.floor(tokenWeiPrice)`. But like I said, `require("bignumber.js")` and use it everywhere. Of course, you'll need to make sure you round intermediate results before passing them to your contract. Ideally, given a `BigNumber` named `x`, use `x.toFixed()` in order to pass it as a proper string.

Comment: Hi goodvibration thanks for your answer I corrected it and it works

Comment: NP, I just wrote an answer to clarify these two comments properly. Check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `const tokenWeiPrice = (answers.priceEur / ethEur) * Math.pow(10, 18);`

Problem #1: `10 ^ 18 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Problem #2: `tokenWeiPrice` is not necessarily an integer.

You should use `BigNumber` conclusively for the purpose of interacting with contracts.

If `ethers.js` doesn't support this type of input, then before passing variable `x` of type `BigNumber` to your contract, use `x.toFixed()` in order to convert it into a proper string.

For example:

```
let BigNumber = require("bignumber.js");

const tokenWeiPrice = new BigNumber(10).pow(18).times(priceEur).dividedToIntegerBy(ethEur);

const contract = await factory.deploy(
   answers.maxSupply,
   answers.eventName,
   answers.symbol,
   0,
   expireAfter,
   tokenWeiPrice.toFixed()
);
```